# Django Admin - Prepopulate field and set readonly

Tags: django, field, admin, readonly, populate

i want to set a field (current user) in a model automatically when an object gets created or is being updated and make it readonly, so the user can not change it:

In order to prepopulate the field:

```
@admin.register(Model)
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('field_1', 'user')

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(ModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['user'].initial = request.user
        return form
```

This works, but when i then want to make the field readonly using:

```
readonly_fields=('user', )
```

the app crashed with error:

```
KeyError at /admin/api/model/add/
'user'
```

Can anybody help me out and explain how i can reach my goal using django admin?

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A work around I found was this:

```
form.base_fields['user'].disabled = True
```

You can also add a help text by:

```
form.base_fields['user'].help_text = "some help text"
```

So in your code it would be:

```
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(ModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['user'].initial = request.user
        form.base_fields['user'].disabled = True
        form.base_fields['user'].help_text = "This field is not editable"
        return form
```

Then you don't have to use `readonly_fields`

Answer (score 2):

Admin provides a method called `save_model` which you can use to add the current user to the object when it's saved;

```
@admin.register(Model)
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: ya i know that already and this is where i can definetly set the current user BUT... the user still can select any user from the dropdown in the form...how can i disable this?

Comment: @Creativecrypter providing the user with a select field is therefore not what you should do. If they have no choice, don't give them the illusion of a choice. Either don't show the field in the form or pass the user to the form & have a select box with only one choice if you really want to show the field.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the get_readonly_fields() method on the ModelAdmin

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    try:
        return 'user',
    except AttributeError:
        return super().get_readonly_fields(request, obj)
```